# Calling a huge object inside v-for causing massive lag?

Tags: performance, vue.js, v-for

recently I'm working on a project showing sport events data

While v-for through the events array (which is around 500~2000 length), I'll call a method in each to show their participants name

```
<div v-for="event in eventArr" :key="event.id">
   <template v-if="mappingObj[event.id]">
     <div class="participantName">
     {{ getCorrespondParticipants (
            mappingInfo[event.id][mappingId],
            mappingInfo[event.id][sportId]) 
      }}
     </div>
   </template>
</div>
```

what it looks like in template, mappingObj is a object collecting all event data with event id as key, its length is around 500~2000(same as the origin events array)

```
getCorrespondParticipants (pidArr, sportId) {
                this.participantListObj[sportId];
            });
            // this part was supposed to get corresponded participants data from the object, returning this.participantListObj[sportId][pid in pidArr]
            return pArr;
   },
```

The method was trying to get the participants info, tho even if I remove all the lines just left 'this.participantListObj[sportId]' there(so it basically did nth but calling the obj), it still causing massive lag result to slow performance for my page, not to mention there's another method to get the league info

```
participantListObj () {
            let cloneObj = JSON.parse(
                JSON.stringify(this.totalParticipantList)
            );
            for (let sportId in cloneObj) {
                cloneObj[sportId] = cloneObj[sportId].reduce(
                    (pObj, item) =>
                        Object.assign(pObj, { [item.participant_id]: item }),
                    {}
                );
            }

            return cloneObj;
        },
```

which would looks like...

```
participantListObj :{
    1: {
          123:{
                 participant_id: 123
                 name_EN: 'Player',
                 name_CN: '玩家'
              },
          ...(18000+)
       }
}
```

The obj is participants list object under each sport Id, made from a participants array list which length could be around 18000, in this case the page has only one sport that is soccer. Did I did anything wrong?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's much easier to help you with code if you copy-paste the text (formatted as Code using the brackets { } button) rather than linking to images of code. I'm happy to swing back and help once you've made the change. :)

Comment: Sure thing Imma post the code now

Comment: Ahhh I see. The short answer is, yes, the number of items is a HUGE problem. I would not expect any client side framework to gracefully handle 18,000 rows of data.

Comment: The short answer (which has many ways of doing), is you need to be doing some form of pagination to pull clumps of participants at a time server-side. I'm not sure where this data is coming from, but at a very high level, find a way to work with less data at once.

Comment: The events data itself is really short, but from the data comes with only their participant id, what I'm trying to achieve is find the participant data with the id from that obj btw

Comment: Why do you need someone's web browser to load all 18,000 objects in order to accomplish that? Where is the data originally coming from? Is there a way to query that directly?

Comment: When you search for someone's username on Twitter, your browser doesn't download all 330,000,000 usernames and then filter in your browser. You're asking, similarly for (2,000 events * 18,000 participants) the browser to do 36 million comparisons. That feels like a lot, and potentially unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah it seems stupid to load all the data while I only need like 1000 of them, it's from our back-end engineer :P I'll ask them to add a search API then